# How to completely remove python2 from OSX so that Brew Install NEOVIM and have the latest version of Python

Tags: python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, pip, homebrew

Please include Terminal Steps to remove this pip error and python2

```
|===> pip install homebrew
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: homebrew in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (0.2.1)


|===> pip install homebrew
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: homebrew in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (0.2.1)
____________________

|===> brew install neovim
-bash: brew: command not found
____________________

|===> pip install brew
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting brew
  Downloading brew-0.1.4.zip (48 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 48 kB 386 kB/s 
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/0q/n_flnz9j637ds046sshnyvzc0000gp/T/pip-install-K9LQMe/brew/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/0q/n_flnz9j637ds046sshnyvzc0000gp/T/pip-install-K9LQMe/brew/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/0q/n_flnz9j637ds046sshnyvzc0000gp/T/pip-pip-egg-info-jnO1ML
         cwd: /private/var/folders/0q/n_flnz9j637ds046sshnyvzc0000gp/T/pip-install-K9LQMe/brew/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/0q/n_flnz9j637ds046sshnyvzc0000gp/T/pip-install-K9LQMe/brew/setup.py", line 22, in <module>
        with open('requirements.txt') as fid:
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

|===> pip uninstall python2
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
WARNING: Skipping python2 as it is not installed.
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the _pip install homebrew_ ? If that's your system Python 2, uninstalling it is probably a bad idea.

Comment: 1 have you visited the "more information here"  URL in that warning? 2. I very highly doubt uninstalling python 2 will help you do anything other than get "error command not found" instead of warnings when you try to run `pip` so what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the native python2 macos installation alone, chances are some of your system utilities need it.
If you need homebrew to install python3, do as follows:

**[macOS Requirements](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation)**

- A 64-bit Intel CPU 1
- macOS High Sierra (10.13) (or higher)
- Command Line Tools (CLT) for Xcode: `xcode-select --install, developer.apple.com/downloads or Xcode`
- A Bourne-compatible shell for installation (e.g. bash or zsh)

**then, on command line:**

as shown [here](https://brew.sh/):

```
 $ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

or as recommended [there](https://theptrk.com/2020/05/02/how-to-install-python-3-on-mac-using-homebrew/):

```
mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

After `homebrew` is installed, you can `brew install python3`, as explained [here](https://theptrk.com/2020/05/02/how-to-install-python-3-on-mac-using-homebrew/)

### Note:

`pip install homebrew` will install a python package from [pipy](https://pypi.org/search/?q=homebrew) that you can import from python. IDK what that package does, but chances are it is a utility that uses python to help generate `brew installable` applications - probably not what you want!

Comment: Thank you, was able to get HomeBrew Insatalled to then install NeoVim